# How to prevent change JQuery UI's Autocomplete Combobox

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using the JQueryUI Autocomplete Combobox at the following link http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox. How can I prevent a change? I only allow a change on a condition and it is still calling a  menuselect event w/ ui-autocomplete-item and allowing the change. That is line 6881 "this._value( item.value ); of the jquery-ui-1.10.3.js.

Everything worked prior to the change of a select to a jquery ui autocomplete combobox and everything would be fine now if I could prevent the menuselect function.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "prevent a change?"   If you don't want the user to change the box under certain conditions, then why not just disable the box?  Also, showing us your code would be nice.

Comment: I do not want to disable the box as value is not passed to the form and the asp.net controller throws a validation error. I want to overwrite the control and cancel the change if a condition isn't met. This jsfiddle link is good for an example. http://jsfiddle.net/hAM9H/929/

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the condition and event.preventDefault in the select event...